# Find 2nd Highest entry as per Column A in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to find second highest value on conditional basis?

Example for, If in column A(ID) has value 'a' and column B(Score) has values (1,2,3) which belongs to 'A' ID.So, here second highest entry will be '2'.

I want to find second highest value which belongs to respective ID.

[image]

Can anyone provide me desired formula to achieve expected output?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where was your problem?  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **D2** enter the array formula:

```
=LARGE(IF(A$2:A$7=A2,B$2:B$7),2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Formula will be as per below

{=SMALL(IF(A:A=A2,B:B),2)}

Answer (score 0):

Use the AGGREGATE() function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$7/($A$2:$A$7=A2),2)
```

[image]